# Can my supervisor verbally put me in Performance improvement plan(PIP) from past date?

Tags: performance

My supervisor has mentioned recently in an email that I am in PIP, however I am not aware if I agreed for any PIP and since which day I am in PIP. Also, I have never singed any documents for PIP not sent any emails or chats agreeing that I am in PIP. I remember my supervisor explained me about PIP and that why an employee is placed in PIP but I don't know if they can verbally tell me that I am in PIP from so and so date in the past.

Is this fair? What to do?

Comment: We are missing a ton of information... Generally your supervisor should have made it 100% clear to you,  that you are in a PIP, but workplaces often aren't fair. We don't know your contract either. Talk to your supervisor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He cannot, however, it may have happened that he has put you in PIP and not informed you. A formal consent is not sought from the employee to put him in PIP, nor you are required to be put sign any documents for that. HR would have been informed, you can discuss with them as well.

PIP means you are not doing well in your job. You need to be careful as if you don't pass the PIP stage, you could be fired from the job. I will suggest you document the fact that you were not aware you have been put on PIP. Also ask your manager to share key improvement area's which he is tracking as a part of PIP. Also ask him the duration for the same and set up a regular meeting to ensure that your progress is recorded and tracked. Ideally your manager should be doing all this, but looking at your question it seems he has not done a good job communicating or managing you PIP.

I will also suggest to take a look at your performance and see if putting you on PIP is justified. If there are performance issues, either fix them, or look for  a new job.

Comment: While I agree an employer doesn’t have to have the employee’s approval to place that employee on a performance improvement plan, because logically no employee would ever agree to doing that, I don’t agree they would put the employee on a PIP without telling the employee (defeats the purpose of a PIP).  What is clear is the author should find out, what thsystem need to do, to satisfy the improvement plan.

Comment: You do need to be notified that you are on a pip and should have a documented process